# javascript how to foreach show data json object

Tags: javascript

This is my JSON data:

```
"data": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "username": "admin",
    "name": "admin",
    "email": "admin@admin.com",
    "job_title": "admin",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null,
    "admin_role": {
      "id": 1,
      "user_id": 1,
      "name": "Admin",
      "created_at": "2018-10-23 11:00:55",
      "updated_at": "2018-10-23 11:00:58",
    }
  },
...
```

I'm trying to run a `foreach` loop, this is my javascript code:

```
 $.each(data, function (key, value) {
    rows = rows + '<tr>';
    rows = rows + '<td>' + value.username + '</td>';
    rows = rows + '<td>' + value.admin_role.name + '</td>';
    rows = rows + '<td data-id="' + value.id + '">';
    rows = rows + '<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-item" class="btn btn-primary edit-item">Edit</button> ';
    rows = rows + '<button class="btn btn-danger remove-item">Delete</button>';
    rows = rows + '</td>';
    rows = rows + '</tr>';
});
```

but the line `value.admin_role.name` throws an error:

> user.js:66 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null

this is what I get when I run a `console.log(value)`:

[image]

Comment: Instead of image post actual data.

Comment: I am not good at English Please explain more.

Comment: Because in some objects you might be having admin_role as null

Comment: `console.log(value)` to see what you get

Comment: @nishant yes some object not data in admin_roles

Comment: replace `value.admin_role.name` with `value.admin_role?value.admin_role.name:"default value when there is no admin role"`

Comment: i update image console.log(value) already

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before accessing any property on an object, it's a good practice to check if the object is not null or undefined. In your case admin_role is null and hence you see that error.

Change your method to this:

```
 $.each(data, function (key, value) {
         var role_name = value.admin_role ? value.admin_role.name : '';

        rows = rows + '<tr>';
        rows = rows + '<td>' + value.username + '</td>';
        rows = rows + '<td>' + role_name  + '</td>';
        rows = rows + '<td data-id="' + value.id + '">';
        rows = rows + '<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-item" class="btn btn-primary edit-item">Edit</button> ';
        rows = rows + '<button class="btn btn-danger remove-item">Delete</button>';
        rows = rows + '</td>';
        rows = rows + '</tr>';
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the value before setting it into the string.

Finally to add it to your html, as you are constructing it directly, you can do it by setting the innerHTML property in the required element.

```js
const data = [
  {
    username: "homer",
    admin_role:
      {
        name: "Nucelar security responsible"
      }
  },
  {
      username: "marge",
      admin_role: { 
        name: "Dangerous housekeeping" 
      }
  }, 
  {username: "bart"} 
];
let rows = '';
 $.each(data, function (key, value) {
    rows = rows + '<tr>';
    rows = rows + '<td>' + value.username + '</td>';
    rows = rows + '<td>' + (value.admin_role?value.admin_role.name:'No role provided') + '</td>';
    rows = rows + '<td data-id="' + value.id + '">';
    rows = rows + '<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-item" class="btn btn-primary edit-item">Edit</button> ';
    rows = rows + '<button class="btn btn-danger remove-item">Delete</button>';
    rows = rows + '</td>';
    rows = rows + '</tr>';
});

document.getElementById('root').innerHTML = rows;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="root"></div>
```